# Disable a parent ModalPopupExtender for child ModalPopupExtender

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

I am using ModalPopupExtender on a asp.net worbform page.

The scenario would be

1. I opended up a ModalPopup, the background was disabled, which is good.
2. Then I clicked a button in that ModalPopup which triggers another ModalPopup to show.
3. At this point, The parent one is showing under the child one, but over the modal background, and still movable, and clickable,

Are there any ways to make the parent popup disabled?

```
<asp:Panel ID="ParentPanel" runat="server">
   <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
       <content>
         <div>Some content</div>
         <button onClientClick="$find('ChildBehavior').show();">Show chirld popup </button>

         <asp:Button runat="server" 
           ID="HiddenTargetControlForParentModalPopup" 
           Enabled="false" style="display:none"/>
         <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ParentPopupExtender"
           runat="server" 
           BehaviorID="ParentBehavior" 
           PopupControlID="ParentPanel"
           TargetControlID="HiddenTargetControlForParentModalPopup"                
           BackgroundCssClass="modal-bg"  />
       </content>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Panel>

<asp:Panel ID="ChildPanel" runat="server"  >
   <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" >
       <content>
         <div>Some other content</div>
         <asp:Button runat="server" 
           ID="HiddenTargetControlForModalPopup" 
           Enabled="false" 
           style="display:none" />
         <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender 
           ID="ChildPopup" runat="server" 
           BehaviorID="ChildBehavior"  
           PopupControlID="ChildPanel"
           TargetControlID="HiddenTargetControlForModalPopup"
           BackgroundCssClass="modal-bg"/>
      </content>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Seems to be a [known bug](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/27971), You can try out this fix: https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/3f82b2bd9ccdd0f573583d7cb0e25bbb46d98ae0

Comment: @Mikhail Tymchuk Thank you!